# Observe Microsoft PowerPoint actions in OSX app

Tags: macos, vba, applescript, powerpoint

I need to observe powerpoint actions in my OSX app

Scenario: I need to perform some actions in my OSX application when user clicks on save button in PowerPoint. Is there any ways to to this.
I have achieved this functionality in Windows application by VBA Macro Events, but in PowerPoint Mac version the VBA Macro Events are not supported.

Thanks in advance

Please help me